# How to have more than 20 custom domains on App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I have many App Engine services (approx 50). I would like to have a custom domain for each of them. I used to create an entry in dispatch.yaml for each custom domain for the routing to the correct service. However, there is a [hard limit of 20 routes in the dispatch.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/reference/dispatch-yaml).

Is there any way to have one custom domain per service?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you given [Google App Engine Limits](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/reference/dispatch-yaml#limits)

Stated that:

> The dispatch file can contain up to 20 routing rules. When specifying the URL string, neither the hostname nor the path can be longer than 100 characters.

The next thing you should do is to file a bug under the [Issue tracking system and product feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

Disclaimer: This doesn't have a specific ETA but you can keep track of its progress once you create the bug.

Hope it helps.